# Can ActiveRecord's :offset "wrap around", so that all records are returned?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My lookup uses the `:offset` option (say, `:offset => 50`) and the pages using this lookup are paginated. So page 1 begins with the record whose ID is 51.

The problem is that the first 50 records never get to show up, because the lookup doesn't "wrap around". That is, if there are 200 total records, and I do `:offset => 50`, the collection from the lookup does not include records 1-50. Is there any way to instruct the lookup to "wrap around", so that it includes all 200 records - but they are ordered such that they begin at record #51?

Comment: That's what offset does. If you want all the records but "starting" at a different place, get all the records and rotate the array. Not sure why you'd want that, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Offset are only for limiting which records are selected; so you shouldn't use that if you want everything. If your page sizes are 50 and you can assume your records are always perfectly in sequence (probably not a good long term assumption), you can specify an order like:

```
Model.order('id < 50, id')
```

If you're loading these records all at once anyway, rotating the records in memory may be okay if the dataset remains manageable:

```
Model.all.rotate(50)
```